# When converting Int to String, it doesn't display [Swift]

Tags: ios, string, swift, int

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //textField do valor A
    @IBOutlet weak var valueA: UITextField!
    //textField do valor B
    @IBOutlet weak var valueB: UITextField!
    //textField do valor
    @IBOutlet weak var valueC: UITextField!
    //declarando as labels string que serão transformadas em int
    var valueBint: Int = 0
    var valueAint: Int = 0
    var valueCint: Int = 0
    //valor de delta em int
    var deltaValue: Int = 0


    @IBAction func calcularButton(sender: UIButton) {
       let valueAint = Int(valueA.text!)
       let valueBint = Int(valueB.text!)
       let valueCint = Int(valueC.text!)
        //conta do delta
        deltaValue = (valueBint! * valueBint!) - (4 * valueAint! * valueCint!)
        print(deltaValue)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var deltaValueS: UILabel!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
           deltaValueS.text = deltaValue.description
        }
    }
```

This is my code. I want the int `deltaValue` to appears as a String in `deltaValueS` Label. I tried many things, but the value doesn't appear.
I tried:

- `deltaValueS.text = "∆ is \(deltaValue)"`
- `deltaValueS.text = "∆ is" + String(deltaValue)`
- `deltaValueS.text = deltaValue.description`

But none works. The problem isn't in the math, the number gets printed for me and the `deltaValue` is right.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you should put the line of code to set the text after the `print(deltaValue)`, not only inside the `viewDidLoad`!

Comment: you need to set value for deltaValueS is after caliculation done

Comment: Write this deltaValueS.text = "∆ is \(deltaValue)" after print(deltaValue). This should be work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this easily by using a property observer.
This will automatically set the text whenever the deltaValue changes.

Try this:

```
var deltaValue: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.deltaValueS.text = "\(deltaValue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: This also worked for me, but I found easier to do as @luk2302 said. There's any difference between the two ways that can bother me in the future?
Thank you!

Comment: The only thing i can see if you use @Andey's answer is if you edit the `deltaValue` from another function than `calcularButton`, you also have to manually set the `deltaValueS.text` afterwards. What's nice with the property observer is that you define the logic once, and it gets fired every time you change the `deltaValue`, regardless of where you made the change. But hey.. whatever floats your boat :)

Answer (score 0):

// try like this

```
@IBAction func calcularButton(sender: UIButton) {
   let valueAint = Int(valueA.text!)
   let valueBint = Int(valueB.text!)
  let valueCint = Int(valueC.text!)
  //conta do delta
   deltaValue = (valueBint! * valueBint!) - (4 * valueAint! * valueCint!)
   self.deltaValueS.text = "\(deltaValue)"
   print(deltaValue)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

deltaValueS.text = deltaValue.description in the viewDidLoad() will not calculate each time you press the button.

You have to put your function in the @IBAction func calcularButton

```
    @IBAction func calcularButton(sender: UIButton) {
   let valueAint = Int(valueA.text!)
   let valueBint = Int(valueB.text!)
   let valueCint = Int(valueC.text!)
    //conta do delta
    deltaValue = (valueBint! * valueBint!) - (4 * valueAint! * valueCint!)
    print(deltaValue)
    deltaValueS.text = "∆ is " + String(deltaValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laffen's solution follows best practices. Think about it this way - you always want the label text to match the value of your variable. So every time someone sets the variable, the text of your label must change. In other words, you will only have to write one line of code in calcularButton: and then later in clearButtonPressed: etc.